# React + Styled Components: Mixing CSS and JS style object?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a few styled components like so:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 40px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 57px;
  width: 331px;
`;

export default Button;
```

Nothing special there. Just styles like it's supposed to be.

However, when I actually use them in my bigger dumb components that are composed of other little components, I find myself styling them using a style object. This is for things like adding extra margin, positioning, and sizing.

```
const AuthenticationForm = ({
  visible,
}) => {
  return (
    <CenteredOverlay style={{ display: visible ? 'flex' : 'none' }}>
      <Box style={styles.box}>
        <img src={require('../images/logo.png')}
          style={styles.logo}
          alt="logo"
          width="60"
          height="60"
        />
        <TextInput placeholder='email' />
        <TextInput placeholder='password' />
        <PrimaryButton active>
          SIGN IN
        </PrimaryButton>
        <Hr />
        <div style={styles.facebookContainer}>
          <span style={styles.alternateLoginText}>
            You can also sign in with
          </span>
          <Button color='#003D82' style={styles.facebookButton}>
            Facebook
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Box>
    </CenteredOverlay>
  );
}

const styles = {
  alternateLoginText: {
    fontSize: '12px',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    opacity: '0.6',
    marginRight: '15px',
  },
  facebookContainer: {
    padding: '12px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  facebookButton: {
    width: '222px',
    height: '42px',
  },
  logo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -30,
  },
  box: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '447px',
  },
  container: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
}

export default AuthenticationForm;
```

It feels odd and kinda counterproductive to the point of using styled components, which is supposed to make my life easier? Now I have to write things two ways?

Please enlighten me if I'm doing things the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are missing out how to actually use styled components, if you want to style any other component using styled components you can just use this pattern:

```
const ButtonStyle = styled(Button)`
    color: #003D82;
    width: '222px';
    height: '42px';
`;

<ButtonStyle>
     Facebook
 </ButtonStyle>
```

and use it as usual

More over [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components)

Comment: But what about positioning? Like sometimes I want the component to have margin-bottom: 10px in one component, width: 100px in another, etc

Comment: yeah, you could do that using this approach, here in this case if you give `margin-bottom: 10px` to the `Link` it will apply this property to the component's root element, `a` in this case

Comment: But won't I have to either 1) create a special Link component every time I want to change the margin or 2) expose a margin-bottom prop? Neither of them seem any better than just using the `style={styles.link}` approach

Comment: No why do you want to create a `Link` component you are just confusing it with my example, in your case you can use `const ButtonStyle = styled(Button)`

Comment: Yeh but my point is, if I have 10 different buttons and their only difference is 1px each in margin-top, how would I build that?

Comment: Yeah, styled components might help you where you need more of css to apply to an element, but ofcourse if you want to apply one or two properties, there is no harm in using the style prop, I personally mix them both, Another good framework css is [tachiyons](http://tachyons.io/), this is just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use [extend](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) method, no need to mix between the two ways of styling your components!

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  ...etc
`;

export default Button;
```

---

```
const FacebookButton = Button.extend`
   width: '222px';
   height: '42px';
   color='#003D82'
`;
const AuthenticationForm = ({
  visible,
}) => (
  <FacebookButton>
    Facebook
  </FacebookButton>
)
```

Comment: My concern is not about the facebook button but about having to style things half using the style object in JS and half in CSS

Comment: Yes exactly, i just showed you an example of how you can use only one way! no need to mix, it applies to everything!